# How to convert/parse string array to double?

Tags: c#, arrays, string, parsing, compare

I have a string array with text and numbers. I extracted a number from it but I can't get it into an `int` or `double` variable to use later for comparing or anything.

Instead, I used Compare method which is not working like I wanted to, to output bigger number from those 2 strings.
What I want is to just put the number in variable or have that compare method work. Thank you I am a beginner.

```
string[] Months = new string[12];
            Months[0] = "Január 1"; //1
            Months[1] = "Február 0"; //2
            Months[2] = "Marec 4,5"; //3
            Months[3] = "Apríl 8.3";  //4
            Months[4] = "Máj 13";   //5
            Months[5] = "Jún 17.3";  //6
            Months[6] = "Júl 20.5";     //7
            Months[7] = "August 21";    //8
            Months[8] = "September 15"; //9
            Months[9] = "October 8";    //10   
            Months[10] = "November 4";   //11
            Months[11] = "December 1.4";   //12

double result = 0;
double result2 = double.Parse(Months[5].Substring(Months[5].IndexOf(" ")).TrimStart());
                
//double.TryParse(double.Parse(Months[5].Substring(Months[5].IndexOf(" ")).TrimStart()), out result);
Console.WriteLine(result2);


 if (string.Compare(Months[4].Substring(Months[4].IndexOf(" ")).TrimStart(), 
Months[5].Substring(Months[5].IndexOf(" ")).TrimStart()) > 0)
{
//Console.WriteLine("1");
Console.WriteLine(Months[4].Substring(Months[4].IndexOf(" ")).TrimStart());
}
```

Comment: I don't understand: "*I can't get it into an int or double variable*". In your code, `result2` is a double. Can you clarify your problem some more?

Comment: Ou ye sorry forgot to add the error 
System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'   
this is the error for the double result2 = ....

Comment: I copied your code verbatim and did not get an error. Are you sure what you have posted is the same code that you are trying to execute?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the numeric part of each, in an array:

```
var nums = Months.Select(m => double.Parse(m.Split()[1]));
```

The `Split()` without a parameter splits the string into an array, using any whitespace as the separator. We then select the second entry in the split array to access just the numeric part, and pass that to `double.Parse()` to parse each sub-string as a double.

The `Months.Select()` is a linq function, and will require adding a using for `System.Linq` if you want to learn more, I'd suggest learning more about how linq works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `double.Parse(yourString, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` to parse your strings, if you split them into parts first by the space in the strings.

```
string[] Months = new string[12];
Months[0] = "Január 1"; //1
Months[1] = "Február 0"; //2
Months[2] = "Marec 4,5"; //3
Months[3] = "Apríl 8.3";  //4
Months[4] = "Máj 13";   //5
Months[5] = "Jún 17.3";  //6
Months[6] = "Júl 20.5";     //7
Months[7] = "August 21";    //8
Months[8] = "September 15"; //9
Months[9] = "October 8";    //10   
Months[10] = "November 4";   //11
Months[11] = "December 1.4";   //12

var parts = Months[5].Split(" ");

double result2 = double.Parse(parts[1], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Console.WriteLine(result2); // Prints 17,3

var month4Parts = Months[4].Split(" ");
var month5Parts = Months[5].Split(" ");

var month4AsDouble = double.Parse(month4Parts[1], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var month5AsDouble = double.Parse(month5Parts[1], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
if (month4AsDouble < month5AsDouble) // If 13 < 17,3
{
    Console.WriteLine(month5AsDouble);
}
```

Comment: Okay thank you very much. I understand everything except "CultureInfo.InvariantCulture" part could you explain it to me?

Comment: The CultureInfo is used to denote what kind of culture is used. An example could be calendars. Some countries reference calendar dates as dd-mm-yyyy, while others reference them as mm-dd-yyyy. In your case, one and a half can be written as 1.5 in some cases, while others would write it as 1,5. 
Link to docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo?view=net-6.0

Comment: @Burr3to if this answered your question, please mark it as the answer and close the question :)